# When a falling object lands, does the velocity (graph) instantly jump to zero? Or does it “slow down”?

Tags: kinematics, velocity

You drop an object.  It lands before hitting terminal velocity.  What does the velocity graph look like?  discrete or continuous?   Does it instantly go from moving to not moving?   Or does it "gradually" slow down?

There may be a difference between what humans can perceive vs. the reality of what is happening.  I want to graph the reality of what is happening, even if it's not able to be measured.

[image]

Comment: Yes it gradually slows down but as you proposed it happens really fast. This kind of almost infinitely fast changes are sometimes modeled using Dirac delta function.

Comment: It depends on what the object is right? And what it lands on? If it's a ball, tennis ball, bouncy ball it'll probably bounce. If it lands on concrete or in a muddy grassy area, or a swimming pool, that might slow it down a bit before stopping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are representing in your plot is a simplified model of reality. This lets us exctract the most important parts of a phenomenon without caring for all the details that don't really change the overall result.

I'm not completely sure if it's a universal rule, but I learned that nature doesn't like either infinities nor sudden transitions. Slopes can be enormous and vary really rapidly, but not enough to see vertical lines or angles in the plot.

In general, these problems emerge because you are using a simplified model of reality. The true reality is much more complex. In this particular case you forgot that both the object and the ground are elastic, or at least deformable, so that the velocity can decrease in a small but finite amount of time.